# Remove product from WooCommerce mini cart based on another product's quantity

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to have product X removed from the WooCommerce mini cart if the customer removes another product from it, so the conditions for product X to be in the cart is no longer met.

The condition is having at least quantity 8 of a product in the cart which is assigned to product category 15 and 51.

I got it working for the cart page, but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the product from the mini cart after the user updates it and the conditions are not met any more.

Maybe someone can help me to achieve this based on the code that I already tried?

My mini cart uses Ajax, so I tried this:

```
function bierfass_ajax_product_remove() {
    // Get mini cart
    ob_start();

    // Get Bierfass product
    $product_x_id = 13387;

    // Get WooCommerce cart object
    $cart = WC()->cart;

    // Initialize flag variable
    $conditions_met = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( '51', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) && has_term( '15', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            if ( $cart_item['quantity'] >= 8 ) {
                $conditions_met = true;
                break; // exit the loop bc we found the what we're looking for
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if conditions are met, else remove product X from cart
    if ( $conditions_met == false ) {
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $product_x_id ) {
                $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    WC()->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();

    woocommerce_mini_cart();

    $mini_cart = ob_get_clean();

    // Fragments and mini cart are returned
    $data = array(
        'fragments' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', array(
            'div.widget_shopping_cart_content' => '<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">' . $mini_cart . '</div>'
            )
        ),
        'cart_hash' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_hash', WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() ? md5( json_encode( WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() ) ) : '', WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() )
    );

    wp_send_json( $data );

    die();

    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_remove', 'my_ajax_product_remove' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_remove', 'my_ajax_product_remove' );
```

with this js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mini_cart_item a.remove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $(this).attr("data-product_id"),
        cart_item_key = $(this).attr("data-cart_item_key"),
        product_container = $(this).parents('.mini_cart_item');

        // Add loader
    product_container.block({
        message: null,
        overlayCSS: {
            cursor: 'none'
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
        data: {
        action: "product_remove",
        product_id: product_id,
            cart_item_key: cart_item_key
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (!response || response.error)
            return;

            var fragments = response.fragments;

             // Replace fragments
            if (fragments) {
                $.each(fragments, function (key, value) {
                    $(key).replaceWith(value);
                });
            }

            // Update cart
            $(document.body).trigger('wc_update_cart');
        }
    });

});
```

But this did not work at all.

This is the code that I use to remove product X from the cart in the cart page (working):

```
function check_cart_after_update() {

    // Get product X
    $product_x_id = 13387;

    // Get WooCommerce cart object
    $cart = WC()->cart;

    // Initialize flag variable
    $conditions_met = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( '51', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) && has_term( '15', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            if ( $cart_item['quantity'] >= 8 ) {
                $conditions_met = true;
                break; // exit the loop bc we found the what we're looking for
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if conditions are met, else remove product X from cart
    if ( $conditions_met == false ) {
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $product_x_id ) {
                $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
// Run the check_cart_after_update() function on the cart and checkout pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'check_cart_after_update' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'check_cart_after_update' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm stupid.

I could have just added this to my working code:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'check_cart_after_update', 10, 1 );
```